# How I can make the bot can play music in stage channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ytdl

This is client messageCreate in my code:

```
    if (msg.author.bot || msg.channel.type == "dm") return;
    if (msg.content.startsWith(".")){
        const player = await createAudioPlayer();
        const connection = await joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: "935835998397542400",
            guildId: "808674100469432360",
            adapterCreator: msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        });
        await msg.guild.me.voice.setSuppressed(false);
        const stream = await ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21qNxnCS8WU", { 
            filter: 'audioonly',
            quality: 'highestaudio',
            highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
         });
        const resource = await createAudioResource(stream);
        await player.play(resource);
    }
});
```

When I send "." in discord, the bot just join the stage channel but it doesn't play music in there. I spend all day to fix this error but it doesn't work

**Version package:**

**Nodejs:** v16.13.0

**Discord.js:** v13.6.0

**Npm:** v8.3.2

Comment: Have you added the `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` intent?

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have to call:

```js
connection.subscribe(player);
```

Documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/voice/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=subscribe

Guide (with great explanation):
https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#playing-audio

Comment: thank u but it still not working ;((